# I am very confused with this doubt, please clear my doubts

Tags: solidity, dapps, uniswapv3

Question: 1

I want to fork Uniswap V3 core and V3 periphery and create a independent contract with some added feature, Forking is easy but the thing confuses me is that how i can re-deploy it onchain or testnet? There are so many contracts and interfaces, do I need to write deploy script for each of them?

Question: 2

If I don't change anything on core and periphery and want to re-deploy it, just for fun, can I do it? If yes then how? Do I need to write deploy script for each of them just like before? And if no then why?

Answer (score 0):

So for interfaces, you do not need to deploy any of them. Interfaces need to be included in the contracts of other developers using your contracts when they deploy, so you don't need to deploy them at all.

A simple deployment should consist of just the factory and router contract. There's also the universal router contract if you want to route between both V2 and V3 pools at the same time.

As for deployment, its possible both deploy from a script, or also from something like remix. You can check out hardhat deployments, https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying. You will need to specify the network to deploy to and the private key/mnemonic you want to deploy with.

You can also flatten the solidity files with something like https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/advanced/flattening, and then deploy them from remix. Flattening for deployment makes it easy for verification and  deployment in remix because all the contracts end up in one file, and you don't have to worry about dependencies. (You might have to do some simple stuff like delete duplicate license identifiers though).

Comment: So i will have to write just 2 deployment script, one for uniswapV3Factory.sol and another for swapRouter.sol, that's all, right?

Comment: Looks like there's also a periphery contract that wraps uniswap v3 positions into an nft, may or may not need that depending on your application.

Comment: I am creating a Dex, so i need the swapRouter.sol from periphery and uniswapV3Factory.sol from core. So i will have to deploy only these

Comment: Do i need to deploy the library contracts? I am asking because some contracts using those.

Comment: I believe all the libraries in uniswap V3 are used as internal libraries. Internal libraries do not require you to deploy them, and external libraries do.

Comment: Yes, you *should be good with just those 2